# Script cannot find Perl module, but module exists in local subdirectory

Tags: software-installation, perl, raspbian

I'm running a Rasbian strecth 4.9.59-v7+ and I´m trying to run the following software https://github.com/weaknetlabs/warcarrier which looks really neat!

When trying to run the script I receive the following error code:

> Can't locate lib/GMAPS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::GMAPS module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at ./warcarrier line 29

The `GMAPS.pm` cannot be installed via `cpan` to my knowledge. However, the `GMAPS.pm` (with a few other modules) can be found in a subdirectory named lib to the warcarrier software. So far I have tried the following:

Copied the `GMAPS.pm` module to one of the above mentioned folders (`/etc/perl`)

Tried to run the script with `perl -I /home/pi/warcarrier/lib`

Modified the script by adding `use lib /home/pi/warcarrier/lib`;(Gave me the error message that is still missing the `GMAP.pm`, However `@inc` now includes the `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib directory`.

> Can't locate lib/GMAPS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::GMAPS module) (@INC contains: /home/pi/warcarrier/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at ./warcarrier line 30

Tried to import the `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib` to `@inc` with `export PERL5LIB=/home/pi/warcarrier/lib`. Error message shows that the path `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib` was NOT included in the path where `@inc` looked for `GMAPS.pm` when the script was run if that means something to anyone.

I have ran out of options, any help is much appreciated! Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module exists in `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib` and the script tries to load it as `lib/GMAPS.pm`.

This means that using `-I /home/pi/warcarrier/lib` will cause Perl to look for `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib/lib/GMAPS.pm`.

Use `-I /home/pi/warcarrier` instead.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you and thank you for taking your time to clean up my question!